# WCF service in Azure worker role slow on first request after being idle

Tags: azure, timeout, python-idle, azure-worker-roles, servicehost

We have an Azure worker role that exposes a RESTful WCF service (using System.ServiceModel.Web) through a ServiceHost. The performance is irreproachable on massive traffic, but it seems like the response time is significantly higher (more than five seconds) on the first request when the role has been idle for some time. Does anyone know what might cause this?

Answer (score 1):

The default AppPool timeout is 20 minutes. Might you be running into this? If so, you can add something like this to a startup script to change the timeout:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:applicationPools -applicationPoolDefaults.processModel.idleTimeout:00:00:00
```

Here's [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9583181/272109) I posted, to a different question, discussing this further.

Comment: +1 Do you know why the default Azure IIS AppPool timeout is set to 20 minutes?  It seems like every Azure user I've talked to needs to remove the AppPool timeout.

Comment: The setting is consistent with Windows Server AppPool timeout, which is also 20 minutes.