# MVC3 EF app in Azure, why do I have to warm it up every once a while?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, azure, azure-web-roles

I am testing my MVC3 + EF app hosted in Azure. The problem I am having now is that every once a while, say 4-5 hours or a day, when I try to visit the page, it is very slow. It takes about 6-8 seconds to load, then the second load would be a lot faster. I have static content cahced, js at the bottom of the page. So I suspect this is because of warm up, but my question here is why do I have to warm it up once a while.

PS: my app is deployed in production environment, I haven't launched it, so it is only me and my team mate been visiting it so far, it has less then 10-20 page requests from us in day, mostly happen at night time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF service in Azure worker role slow on first request after being idle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352363/wcf-service-in-azure-worker-role-slow-on-first-request-after-being-idle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a few other SO answers (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352363/wcf-service-in-azure-worker-role-slow-on-first-request-after-being-idle)), you're likely running into an AppPool timeout situation. To disable this timeout, you can execute this via startup script:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:applicationPools -applicationPoolDefaults.processModel.idleTimeout:00:00:00
```