# Automatically install Application Initialization in Azure Web Role (SDK v1.8, Windows Server 2012)

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I see Microsoft have released Application Initialization as part of IIS 8.0.  Unfortunately it isn't enabled in the Web Role by default. (by that I mean, "Application Initialization" as a feature of the web server role is not enabled. I know the Web Role has IIS 8.)

Does anyone know how I can enable this from a start-up script?  I've already a number of start-up scripts, but I'm not sure how to add a server role feature.

The module itself appears inside Server Manager under "Server Roles" -> "Web Server (IIS)" -> "Web Server" -> "Application Development" -> "Application Initialization".

It's a shame that this isn't enabled by default as it will be very useful.

thanks

Kris

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First you'll need to install the feature using a startup task:

```
PKGMGR.EXE /iu:IIS-ApplicationInit
```

And then you'll need to configure your site in IIS (**startMode** and **preloadEnabled**):

```
public class WebRole : RoleEntryPoint
{
    public override void Run()
    {
        using (var serverManager = new ServerManager())
        {
            var mainSite = serverManager.Sites[RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id + "_Web"];
            var mainApplication = mainSite.Applications["/"];
            mainApplication["preloadEnabled"] = true;

            var mainApplicationPool = serverManager.ApplicationPools[mainApplication.ApplicationPoolName];
            mainApplicationPool["startMode"] = "AlwaysRunning";

            serverManager.CommitChanges();
        }

        base.Run();
    }

    public override bool OnStart()
    {
        // For information on handling configuration changes
        // see the MSDN topic at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=166357.

        return base.OnStart();
    }
}
```

[I wrote a blog post about this](http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/iis-8-0-application-initialization-module-in-a-windows-azure-web-role/) and you can find [a sample application on GitHub](https://github.com/sandrinodimattia/WindowsAzure-IISApplicationInitializationModule).

Comment: Is there a reason that you chose to override Run rather than OnStart?

Comment: ServerManager class can be found from Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll assembly.

Answer (score 0):

The web role absolutely has IIS 8.0 installed. Id you change the web role to OSVersion=3, it will deploy your app to a Windows Server 2012 image with IIS 8.0.

If you mean the VM (Azure IaaS)?  What I would do is start from Windows Server 2012, remote desktop in, install the core server as you want, sysprep it, capture the image.  This way you have it for re-use in your Azure Image Gallery.  Then you can spin up many VMs from this base image with IIS 8.0 already set up/installed etc.

Comment: I mean that the "Application Initialization" module/feature of the Web Server role is not enabled. So yes, it has IIS 8, just doesn't have Application Initialization enabled.

Comment: What you are looking for can be automated using Package Manager: http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-7-and-above-on-windows-server-2008-or-windows-server-2008-r2 or you can use PowerShell (in a startup task for your web role) to add features to the server: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/01/27/managing-server-features-with-powershell-cmdlets-on-windows-2008-server-r2-beta.aspx