# Programmatically set IIS preloadEnabled

Tags: c#, iis-8

Is it possible to set preloadEnabled="true" for Application Initialization?
The schema for Application in ServerManager doesn't seem to recognize the attribute, so when I set the following, no changes occur.

```
ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();
application = serverManager.Sites[0].Applications[0];
application.SetAttributeValue["preloadEnabled"] = "true";
serverManager.CommitChanges();
```

Is it possible to do this through ServerManager, or another way?

Some context: http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization

Comment: I don't know if you can do it inside the program itself. I do know you can do it from powershell externally ran as an administrator.

Comment: Nearly 6 years later, your exact-same code running against IIS 10 seems to work perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Two things fixed this for me.

1) Using a boolean instead of a string

```
application.SetAttributeValue["preloadEnabled"] = true;
```

2) Installing the Application Initialization first.

Answer (score 2):

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237393/automatically-install-application-initialization-in-azure-web-role-sdk-v1-8-wi)

As you mentioned, you need to install the module first because by default it is not installed  for IIS8. You can do this with a starup task as outlined in Sandrino Di Mattia's answer and blog post (see link).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can do it inside the ASP website itself. I do know you can do it from power shell script ran as an Administrator or elevated permissions.