# How do I exclude folders from ASP.NET precompilation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I'm experimenting with [ClientBuildManager.PrecompileApplication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.clientbuildmanager.precompileapplication%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) in order to [force compiling of my ASP.NET site](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10618600/57428).

I've added a [ClientBuildManagerCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.clientbuildmanagercallback%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and trace all calls to `ReportProgress()` method. Clearly the precompilation will traverse `Content` and some other subfolders of the site where I have no views and so nothing to precompile, so going into those directories is a waste of time.

Is there a way to exclude specific folders from precompilation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I am aware and looking through the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) seems to support that. To do what you want to do I think you would have to write an MSBuild task which, of course, defeats what you are trying to do with ClientBuildManager.PrecompileApplication.